# initialize Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - Vagrant Up

Tags: php, joomla, vagrant, vagrant-provision

I Install Vagrant in my Ubuntu(14.4) System. When i Enter Vagrant Up comment Display following Errors.

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/machine_index.rb:321:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/w3cert/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index.lock (Errno::EACCES)
```

Answer (score 6):

`Permission denied`

means that the file `/home/w3cert/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index.lock` is owned by another user and your current user has no permission.

check who is the owner of your file, if you run any install/command with `sudo` or `root` then your current user will not have access to modify the file.

for now you can change the ownership of all `.vagrant.d` files to your account and you should be able to run the `vagrant up` command

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem. I used Vagrant before and uninstall it. When i tried to reinstall back i had the same error
My solution was to delete the .vagrant.d temp folder  (in your case /home/w3cert/.vagrant.d/)

Hope it works for you as well

Answer (score 0):

As Manuel stated, deleting the .vagrant.d folder will solve the issue.

oddly this happened on windows as well, i didn't install anything new, or reinstall vagrant or anything like that. the only thing i can think of is the power cut we had last week has caused a folder/file lock... although a reboot should solve that :S